# Struts2 AJAX :Get struts 2 action message as ajax response

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, struts2

I am trying to get actionMessage from action by using Ajax call. I am able to get the resultList through AJAX call but not sure how to get action message.

Please give me some Idea .

Comment: The ajax request is handled just like any other request  So whatever the action outputs, it will be sent to the client.try to check in firebug what exactly is coming back from action

Comment: Is the issue that the messages aren't there (adding a getter is the most trivial solution), or you don't know what to do with them and they *are* there?

Comment: Hi Umesh, Idon't see any data related to actionMessage in firebug

Comment: Hi Dave, Yes I am able to get actionMessage in action . Return type for action message is void.So How I need to set it to string and hetter for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix my problem.
After assigning success  action message to string variable(added getter for it), I am able to see the message in firebug!!!